# Tensorflow Exception encountered when calling layer 'tfrp_model'

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting error in the following code, code having some issues.

Here is the code I am using to run this

```
            `import numpy as np
            import pandas as pd
            from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
            from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
            import tensorflow as tf
            import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs

            tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

            ratings_data = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')

            user_item_matrix = ratings_data.pivot(index='user_id', columns='item_id', values='rating').fillna(0)
            train_data, test_data = train_test_split(ratings_data, test_size=0.2)

            user_features = np.random.rand(user_item_matrix.shape[0], 10)
            item_features = np.random.rand(user_item_matrix.shape[1], 10)

            class TFRPModel(tfrs.Model):

                def __init__(self):
                    super().__init__()
                    self.user_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
                    self.item_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
                    self.task = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
                        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()]
                    )

                def call(self, features):
                    user_embeddings = self.user_model(tf.expand_dims(features['user_id'], axis=0))
                    item_embeddings = self.item_model(tf.expand_dims(features['item_id'], axis=0))
                    return user_embeddings, item_embeddings

                def compute_loss(self, features, training=False):
                    user_embeddings, item_embeddings = self(features)
                    return self.task(user_embeddings, item_embeddings)

            model = TFRPModel()

            model.compile(
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.1)
            )


            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({
                'user_id': train_data['user_id'].values,
                'item_id': train_data['item_id'].values
            })

            history = model.fit(dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(32), epochs=10)

            user_id = 5
            user_ratings = user_item_matrix.loc[user_id]
            predicted_scores = model({
                'user_id': np.expand_dims(np.array([user_id]), axis=0),  # expand user_id from 1D to 2D
                'item_id': np.arange(user_item_matrix.shape[1])
            })[1].numpy().flatten()
            recommended_item_ids = np.argsort(-predicted_scores)[:5]

            print(f"Top 5 recommended items for user {user_id}:")
            for item_id in recommended_item_ids:
                print(f"Item ID: {item_id}, Item Name: {item_name_dict[item_id]}")`
```

Can any one give me suggestions to rectify the following error?

Here is the error

```
            `ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'tfrp_model' (type TFRPModel).

            Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 7, but received input with shape (1, 1, 1)

            Call arguments received by layer 'tfrp_model' (type TFRPModel):
            • features={'user_id': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32)', 'item_id': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(4,), dtype=int32)'}`
```

I am trying to run this script to show top five recommended products from a csv file having user_id, item_id, rating, based ratings initial output should show, unable to run it. Need to know the recommended products as the output